# How to send a html file in a webservice response

Tags: html, eclipse, web-services, jakarta-ee

I have the below webservice that returns results in 3 different formats (Json/xml/html) depending on the request type query parameter:

the Url looks something of this sort:

http://xyz/myapp/FoodService/testSelect?query=pizza2&output=html

The method is something of this sort:

```
      @GET
      @Path("/testSelect")
      public Response selectGetTest(@QueryParam("query") String query,@QueryParam("output") String resultType, @Context HttpServletRequest request)
    {

// Build html file manually using buffered writer and return the file
//  
//
//
//}
```

Comment: I would recommend to use HTTP Header "Accept" in the client to specify the format instead of a query param.

Answer (score 0):

After you have the HTML content, create a `ResponseBuilder` object, specifying the HTML `MediaType`. Then, ask that [builder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern) to build the final `Response` object that your method returns.

http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/Response.html#ok-java.lang.Object-javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType-

http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/MediaType.html#TEXT_HTML_TYPE

http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/Response.ResponseBuilder.html#build--